# Cut string after specified character in php

Tags: php, wordpress, character

I try to cut a text after the occurence of a specified character, in this case:

```
“
```

The text example is:

```
...text?“ Text,
```

I tried the following:

```
$pos2 = strpos($title, '“');
if ($pos2 == true) {
             $header_title = substr($title, 0, $pos2);
    {
```

But it always cuts `“`, too. I messed around with adding numbers to $pos2 but couldn't figure it out. How can I cut after the specified character?

Comment: That sample text has **no** text after the char...

Comment: What do you mean by 'cut'? Do you want that part only or you want it removed?

Comment: Edited the Text.

I want it to only give my the part before the “ but including “.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strpos()` command requires 3 parameters

1) The Variable

2) The start column and

3) the numbers of characters

If you just use `substr($title,$pos2)` you get the text from the pos2 column to the end of the string.

```
<?php
$title = 'before“after';
$pos2 = strpos($title, '“');
if ($pos2 !== false) {
    $header_title = substr($title,0, $pos2+1);
} else {
    // you might want to set $header_title to something in here
    $header_title = 'ELSE';
}
echo $header_title;
```

RESULT

```
before“
```

Also test for `not equal false` as strpos returns FALSE if it does not find the character you are searching for

> After all the discussion below I ran it on my local Apache/PHP

```
<?php
$title = 'before“after';
$pos2 = strpos($title, '“');
if ($pos2 !== false) {
    $header_title = substr($title,0,$pos2+1);
} else {
    // you might want to set $header_title to something in here
    $header_title = 'ELSE';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $header_title;?></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div> Ello Wurld</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Produces:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried your way but it still only gives me "before" and not "before“"...

Comment: @letobili Check if you are using the correct char (maybe `"` - If you take a closer look, it's not really `"` , it's slightly tilted). As long as both are the same, you are good to go. Check what char you have in the text and then use it in the `strpos` function.

Comment: Maybe that odd char is just not showing where you are displaying it

Comment: Or was the Odd Char a typo in your questions?

Comment: No, the odd char is correct and I checked it in the text and my code, they are the same.

The odd char is displayed if I don't cut the text.

The substr seems to work. But not the "+1" in it.

Comment: Interesting. I just tested this on localhost and it is actually **not** working... (Even after setting utf-8 and checking page's source). Edit: printing only the result gives that weird result. If you echo something else after that char, it gets diamond `?`

Comment: I am testing it on CLI maybe thats having some wierd effect

Comment: For a quickfix, just do a `$title = str_replace('“', '"', $title);` before and in case that char is really needed, do the opposite after that .. hehe

Comment: I tested it on my Apache and it still works. With no problems at all See additional info. So something else in your code is getting in the way

Comment: As _last resort_, inside the if condition, append the char to the end of the string.

Comment: This is the answer to cut after a char. It has been extensively tested and it worked for both of us. So this a problem that can't be reproduced...

Comment: I tested it on a different text sample with the same character and it worked fine! So it has to be a problem with my original text sample.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be helpful for anyone :

```
$title = 'sometext?"othertext';
$pos2 = strpos($title, '"');

$title = substr($title, 0, $pos2+1);

echo $title;
```

Output:

> sometext?"

---

If you want the text after the `"` mark:

```
$title = 'sometext?"othertext';
$pos2 = strpos($title, '"');

$title = substr($title, $pos2+1);

echo $title;
```

Output:

> othertext

Comment: Note that they have different purposes. Provide the output and you'll see that your code gets whats **after** the `"`, and @RiggsFolly's gets what's **before**...

Comment: Honestly, I do apologize for this, I understood that he want to cut the text after the appearing of the ".  Anyway, sorry for that.

Comment: Dont panic. Maybe he does.

Comment: Also, even if the op does not want it, other people might. I just think that you should make it clear and explain what your code is doing.

Comment: Thank you @FirstOne & RiggsFolly, I edited the answer to make it useful for anyone.